# Error while executing the rcov report, rails stats report and brakeman warnings from Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, statistics, rcov, brakeman

I am using Jenkins for deployment process and it works fine. When i try to take rcov report rails stats report and brakeman warnings.

[ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx] executing command

** [out :: ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx] Starting Unicorn..

command finished in 2228ms

POST BUILD TASK : SUCCESS

END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0

ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.brakeman.BrakemanPublisher aborted due to exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/kannan/.jenkins/workspace/Publisher Dev/brakeman-output.tabs (No such file or directory)

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)

at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1570)

at hudson.FilePath.readToString(FilePath.java:1595)

at hudson.plugins.brakeman.BrakemanPublisher.perform(BrakemanPublisher.java:99)

at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:146)

at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.perform(HealthAwareRecorder.java:331)

    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)

    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)

    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)


    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)

at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:726)

at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1618)

at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)

at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)

at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
```

Publishing rails stats report...

Build failed, skipping rcov coverage report

Build step 'Publish Rcov report' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE

What am i supposed to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/kannan/.jenkins/workspace/Publisher Dev/brakeman-output.tabs (No such file or directory)`

This means Jenkins can't find the report generated by Brakeman. Either you have not set up the job correctly or Brakeman is failing for some reason. You should check the console output for Brakeman errors and verify you have configured the job correctly as [described here](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/jenkins/setup/).